# jQuery ajax: Cannot send dates?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I cannot send any date object through jQuery Ajax, why?

```
var nid = '99';     
var date = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");

$.ajax({
        data: { 
            nid: nid, 
            evs: date, 
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/save_scheduler',
        dataType: "json",
        error:function(xhr,err){        
                return false;
        },
        success: function(res) {
            // console.log(res);
        }   
});
```

I am familiar with jQuery ajax. Usually I have any problem to send variables through it. But I am stocked there..

In server side, I can then catch $_POST['nid'], but cannot get $_POST['evs'].

```
$nid = $_POST['nid'];
$evs = $_POST['evs'];
```

I get this message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: evs in ajax_save_scheduler()
```

Can someone explain why?

/***** Edit ******/

In firebug, I cannot see the date in post tab of the query:

[image]

If I change the date line like this:

```
var evs = "October 13, 2014 11:13:00";
```

It works as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in jQuery 1.7.1 (and before probably) which handles some objects incorrectly. That was fixed in [1.7.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/):

> [#10466](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10466): jQuery.param() mistakes wrapped primitives for deep objects

jQuery tried to traverse the properties of *every* object, even those that don't have any enumerable properties at all. This posed a problem for wrapped primitives, such as `String`, and `Date`.

**Solution:** Upgrade jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

if can you use string type, try toString();

```
data: { 
    nid: nid, 
    evs: date.toString()
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refrain from sending such platform specific objects. Use only primitives. Change the line

```
var date = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
```

to

```
var date = (new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")).toString();
```

This seems pretty pointless here, but the point here is convert all objects to strings using some rule in your Javascript and parse them on the server-side to create server platform compliant `Date` object (if available).